# Restore a Database into a Current Database and merge

Tags: sql-server

I want to know how, or if it is possible, to backup a database then should the user wish, restore that database at a later date and merge it with the one they are currently using.  Both Databases will be using the same tables and have the same fields, the difference is in the data.  Ideally I would like to do this through SQL and not have to get a third party application.  Any ideas or suggestions, I'm kind of in a bind here.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there is a product out there to do this. Think about it, you have db1 and db1' assuming *only* data values have changed, what is correct? People table has Mary Smith in db1 and Mary Winklebauer in db1' - which one should be retained? How would a generic program implement that merging of data? If all your tables have the concept of last modified date, then you can probably figure out which row to preserve. Either way, you'll need to restore the backup to a different catalog and merge that data into target in FK reference order.

Comment: Does it have to be if the user wish? Can it be continously merging the data?

Comment: Is it *every* table or just a select few? You could take your backup now, restore it under a different catalog name and set it to readonly. Then write the merge process (three part naming with merge statements, some SSIS, or some other option other folks will come up with) and let it sit idle until they have need to actually merge the data.

Comment: To be honest I questioned the reasoning for the "backup to merge" myself.  I think @bilinkc is right in the statement of what data is kept and what data is overwritten.  I think what I am going to have to do is when they "restore" the old database to restore it with a different name and set it as read only as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Visual Studio Ultimate or Premium, you can use ["Data Compare"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833428.aspx) feature in Data menu. It can compare data between two tables and have ability to directly update your database or generate update script.